# How can I store an ndarray in a struct when ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim is private?

Tags: rust

The ndarray crate's examples use the following code where the `Array::random` return type is `ArrayBase<S, D>`:

```
let a = Array::random((hash_size, inp_dimensions), Uniform::new(0., 10.));
```

I want to store the result in a struct and therefore need the type. The compiler tells me that it expects `ArrayBase<S, D>` to be of type `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim>`, but `ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim` is private.

How can I store this array in a struct?

Comment: isn't Dim publicly reexported in the ndarray prelude ?

Comment: Thanks, thats it. I let me fool by the compiler-output and then looked the wrong way. Also, 'reexported' types were new to me. (I'm still in my learning phase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dim` is re-exported to the crate's root (see [*re-exporting names with `pub use`*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html#re-exporting-names-with-pub-use)).
When in doubt, you can [search the crate's documentation](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/?search=Dim) for that type by name.

In `ndarray`, there are multiple other useful type aliases that you might wish to use instead of specifying `ArrayBase` directly:

- [`Array<A, D>`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/type.Array.html), equivalent to `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<A>, D>`, explicitly represents an owned array.
- [`Array2<A>`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/type.Array2.html) can be used specifically for owned two-dimensional arrays, thus already defining the dimension type parameter (also `Array1<A>`, `Array3<A>`, and so on).

Comment: What are the benefits to having an owned array over just an array?

Comment: @PetrusTheron That inquiry is unclear. Arrays are owned by default, unless you have a slice, a reference to an array, or for the case of ndarray, an array view. Perhaps you'd like to ask a new question.